# The method 'getApplicationDocumentsDirectory' isn't defined for the type '_MyAppState'

Tags: flutter, dart, methods

so a part of my code is

```
 Future<void> _loadModel() async {
    final bytes =
        await rootBundle.load('assets/deepspeech-0.9.3-models.tflite');
    final directory = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
```

And i keep getting the error:

```
The method 'getApplicationDocumentsDirectory' isn't defined for the type '_MyAppState'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'getApplicationDocumentsDirectory'
```

What should i do? help me please!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have to install [path provider package](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) by running `flutter pub add path_provider` in your terminal. If you already installed it. check whether you are importing it to your file.

Answer (score 11):

Import this...

```
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Answer (score 0):

Add  `path_provider: ^2.0.11` to pubspec.yaml file.

Run Pub Get.

And Import this

> import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';